# Do there exist any elliptic curves $E\mathbb{F}_8$ satisfying either $\# E(\mathbb{F}_8) = 7$ or $\#E(\mathbb{F}_8) = 11$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

As the question title suggests, do there exist any elliptic curves $E(\mathbb{F}_8)$ satisfying either $\# E(\mathbb{F}_8) = 7$ or $\#E(\mathbb{F}_8) = 11$?

Comment: See problem $5.10.f$ in [*Silverman's book*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z90CA_EUCCkC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=elliptic+curve+F8+with+7+points&source=bl&ots=3M7lfxXi-a&sig=r3Nf2g7I3Vr7NvwziTLHg4rEVag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcw47hiqfQAhVE9WMKHT8ADIAQ6AEIKjAD#v=onepage&q=elliptic%20curve%20F8%20with%207%20points&f=false) and the hint to prove the answer is no.

Comment: And see Silverman's hint to use $5.10$, part $e$ for it.